# How to create .jar files with additional resources without using an IDE

Tags: java

How can I create a .jar file which includes both class files and some additional resources(namely images) without the use of an IDE.

Comment: What is your Operating System?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a jar of your project you need to the following command:

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

first make sure that running in command prompt or terminal *jar* is not going to tell you "command not found".

The options and arguments used in this command are:

- The **c** option indicates that you want to create a JAR file.
- The **f** option indicates that you want the output to go to a file
  rather than to stdout.
- **jar-file** is the name that you want the resulting JAR file to have.
- The **input-file(s)** argument is a space-separated list of one or more
  files that you want to include in your JAR file. The input-file(s)
  argument can contain the wildcard * symbol. If any of the
  "input-files" are directories, the contents of those directories are
  added to the JAR archive recursively.

Let's assume you have a directory named **"My Project"** which contains all your java packages, classes, resources, etc. You need to jar "My Project" hence, you should do the following:

1. Navigate to the parent of the directory that contains "My Project" using command prompt (in windows) and terminal (in OSX or linux)
2. execute the jar command as follow (in windows - double quotes around My Project is because of space in directory name, you might not need it)

   jar cf MyProject.jar "My Project"
3. Above command will give you the directory in jar.

For more info on creating jar see [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use maven or ant to reach this goal.

Comment: I dunno what maven or ant is.

Comment: Google helps you. http://maven.apache.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I can only link you to the oracle page : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

The command you are looking for seems to be :

> jar cvf TicTacToe.jar TicTacToe.class audio images

Where audio and images are resource folders.

Good luck,